# ruby file.foreach

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I'm trying to make this test work, but the inner File.foreach complains. It finds the file for variable a, but can't open it while it is there. Is this construct i'm using the right way to open a file within another loop?

(This is not the final test, i'm just trying to get things going)

```
describe "2.1.18" do
  it "CIFS: Only valid users are allowed" do
    if File.exist?('/etc/samba/samba.d/shares.conf')
      authorized_regexp = /^\s*(valid\s+users\s+\W{1}\s+.+)/
      path_regexp = /path/
      inc_regexp = /^\s*include/
      path_count = 0
      a_count = 0

      File.foreach('/etc/samba/samba.d/shares.conf') do |line|
        if mtch = line.match(authorized_regexp)
          a_count += 1
        else
          if mtch = line.match(inc_regexp)
            _, a = line.split('=')
            File.foreach(a) do |pp|
              if mtch = pp.match(authorized_regexp)
                a_count += 1
              end
            end
          end
        end
        if mtch = line.match(path_regexp)
          path_count += 1
        end
      end
      expect(a_count).to eq(path_count)
    end
  end
end
```

The error message
    Norm 2.1.18

```
BIDET CIFS: Only valid users are allowed (FAILED - 1)
Failures:

  1) 2.1.18 CIFS: Alleen geautoriseerde gebruikers hebben toegang
 Failure/Error: File.foreach(a) do |pp|
 Errno::ENOENT:

   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -  /etc/samba/liv_smb.conf
 # ./test_spec.rb:16:in `foreach'
 # ./test_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./test_spec.rb:10:in `foreach'
 # ./test_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 0.00119 seconds (files took 0.11126 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

The file it cannot open.

```
# ls -l /etc/samba/liv_smb.conf

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 247 Jul 14 09:49 /etc/samba/liv_smb.conf
```

**EDIT**:

mudasobwa solved the issue, File.foreach(a.strip) did the trick!

Comment: `File.foreach(a.strip)` should help, I believe it has a trailing `\n`.

Comment: You rule! That was it, thanks alot.

Comment: It's worth posting that as a self-answer as it closes the loop on this question and can help others in the same jam.

Answer (score 0):

mudasobwa provided the solution, i needed to add 'strip' to the 'a' variable since it contains a newline.

```
        File.foreach(a.strip) do |pp|
          if mtch = pp.match(authorized_regexp)
            a_count += 1
          end
        end
```